# Undefined variabel :$ Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

This is the code from `PemesananController`:

```php
function index()
{
    $ruang = \App\ruangan::all();
    $sewa = \App\sewa::all();
    return view('/admin/pesan/index',compact('ruang', 'sewa'));
}

public function cetak_pdf()
{
    $sewa = \App\sewa::all();

    $pdf = PDF::loadview('',['sewa'=>$sewa]);
    return $pdf->download('laporan-guest-pdf')->stream();
}
```

And this is the code that I'm writing to the `index.blade.php`:

```
@foreach($sewa as $r)

@endforeach
```

this my index code :

```php
<a href="{{route('pdf')}}" class="btn btn-success my-3">EXPORT PDF</a>
<table class="table">
    <thead class=" text-primary">
        <th> No</th>
        <th> Nama tamu</th>
        <th> Ruangan</th>
        <th> CheckIn</th>
        <th> CheckOut</th>
        <th colspan="2"> Aksi</th>
    </thead>
    @foreach($sewa as $r)
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>{{$r->nama_guest}}</td>
            <td> {{$r->ruangan}}</td>
            <td> {{$r->created_at}}</td>
            <td>{{ $r->tgl_checkout}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="/admin/{{ $r->id }}/shows" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">lihat</a>
                <a href="/admin/{{ $r->id }}/edits" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
                <a href="/admin/{{ $r->id }}/haps" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Hapus</a>
                <a href="/admin/{{ $r->id }}/checkout" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Checkout</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tbody>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

I'm getting this :

```
Undefined variable: sewa (View:
C:\xampp\htdocs\Hotel_Lido\resources\views\admin\pesan\index.blade.php)
```

Why does it happen? Everything works fine but, when I click on *Export PDF* button the program gives me error.

Comment: what is the route and the error?

Comment: What happens if you `dd($sewa)` on `cetak_pdf` function?

Comment: Is the class start with capital or small sewa or Sema?

Comment: post your model code

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php

use App\Ruangan;
use App\Sewa;

class PemesananController extends Controller
{

    function index()
    {
        $ruang = Ruangan::all();
        $sewa = Sewa::all();

        return view('admin.pesan.index', compact('ruang', 'sewa'));
    }

}
```